# Как добавить статью в андроид приложение?

Tags: android

Сразу извинюсь на случай, если вопрос элементарный - я новичок и сама не смогла найти инфу. В моем приложении есть раздел со статьями (работать они должны без интернета). Внутри будет текст с подчеркиваниями и тп и, что главное, картинки. Так вот, каким образом лучше всего можно создать, хранить и обращаться к файлам со статьями? Буду благодарна за ответ или ссылки на любые материалы по теме.

Comment: Как и во всех любых других веб-приложениях, сайтах и т.д. Статьи создаёте, храните в базе данных. Для андроида вам идеально подойдет sqlite.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Всё зависит от того, какой формат данных у ваших статей и как вы их хотите отображать.

1. Идеальный случай. Кто-то очень умный предоставляет вам статьи в виде JSON, в котором отдельно идут картинки и отдельно блоки текста. Причём в тексте есть только поддерживаемые андроидом тэги форматирования. В этом случае просто сохраните это как-то (файл, БД, etc) и отобразите с помощью RecyclerView, TextView и ImageView.
2. Обычный случай. Вам выдали простой HTML. Там простейшие теги, минимум стилей и картинки не выровнены везде по разному, а наоборот, идут просто между блоками текста, обрамлёнными своими собственными тэгами. Тут немного сложнее, т.к. надо вручную порезать текст на части, убедиться, что отображается всё специальное форматирование текста (жирный, подчёркивание, etc) (если нет - написать специальный код, который это сделает). Далее всё как в п.1.
3. Особо запущенный случай. Вы работаете с потомственным фронт-эндером. Он вам выдал HTML с обилием стилей, картинки везде и всюду по разному расположены, текст их обтекает самыми замысловатыми способами и вообще. И при этом надо сделать так, чтобы оно всё отображалось так же, как и в оригинале, на сайте. Тут у вас будут большие проблемы. В теории можно и на нативных андроид-вьюхах всё это отрисовать, но это будет предельно сложная задача, сопоставимая с написанием собственного движка рендеринга браузера. Тут вам остаётся сдаться и использовать WebView. Оно будет притормаживать, но всё отрисует. Про хранение такого рода данных - см. п.1